# issue creating a named vector with paste

Tags: r, vector

This seems a rudimental question but I can't find an explanation on SO.

I can name a vector like so:

```
values = c("lab1" = "my_lab1", 
           "lab2" = "my_lab2")
values
#      lab1      lab2 
# "my_lab1" "my_lab2"
```

I can create the same vector by using `paste0` to create an element like so:

```
values = c("lab1" = "my_lab1", 
           "lab2" = paste0("my_lab", "2"))
values
#      lab1      lab2 
# "my_lab1" "my_lab2"
```

But when you try to create the name with `paste0`, it causes an error:

```
values = c("lab1" = "my_lab1", 
           paste0("lab", "2") = "my_lab2")
# Error: unexpected '=' in:
# "values = c("lab1" = "my_lab1", 
#            paste0("lab", "2") ="
```

**Why is this?** Considering that the following is true:

```
identical("lab2", paste0("lab", "2"))
[1] TRUE
```

A solution is to use `setNames` but I am interested in why the above is an issue:

```
setNames(c("my_lab1", "my_lab2"), c("lab1", paste0("lab", "2")))
#      lab1      lab2 
# "my_lab1" "my_lab2"
```

I can't see any mention to this in the `vector` section of [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Thanks

Comment: most assignment operations in R only allow literals on the LHS of the `=`, not an expression; the canonical ways are to use `setNames` as you showed, or `names(vec) <- c("a", paste0("b",2))` (which is what `setNames` does internally, it's just a shortcut)

Comment: @r2evans this isn't about an *assignment operation*, it's about *argument names* and how R's parser doesn't evaluate them.

Comment: A generic work-around would be `do.call`, to evaluate an arbitrary function with arbitrary arguments, where any of the function name or argument names could be stored in strings.

Comment: @GregorThomas, the argument value is being assigned to the argument name. It is not _exactly_ the same as creating objects on the console using `=` or `<-`.

Comment: I suppose. I'm one of those rebellious R users who prefers `=` to `<-`, but the most compelling argument I've heard for using `<-` is that it is explicitly clear when you are assigning `<-` vs when you are passing an argument `=`, as the two are fundamentally different. The base solutions/workarounds are pretty different, `assign` vs `do.call`.

Comment: (That said I first started using `=` because when I wrote functions I would start as a script declaring sample/default values with `<-`, and then when I had the script working I wrapped it in `function()`, and I got annoyed of needing to replace all my sample input `<-` with `=` to turn them into default values. So I guess I started preferring `=` because I explicitly wanted to blur the line between assignment and argument tagging ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that named parameters are simply never evaluated. They are assumed to be literal values. Consider the case of

```
foo <- function(a=5, x=10) {a+x}
```

And then you did

```
x <- "a"
foo(x = 2)
foo(paste(x) = 2) # error
```

If you expect the "x" to be evaluated, it can get very confusing what actually is supposed to run. The R parser does not expect to see expressions as parameter names. The grammar is [defined in the R source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/gram.y#L440) There is also a reference to this fact in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-calls-_0028expressions_0029) where it states

> Each argument can be tagged (tag=expr), or just be a simple expression. It can also be empty or it can be one of the special tokens ..., ..2, etc. [...] A tag can be an identifier or a text string.

which does imply the tag cannot be an expression itself.

In the example I used `foo` as a function, but `c` is also just a function. And while it doesn't' have explicit named parameters, it does follow all the same rules for other functions about parameter names.

In the tidyverse/rlang world, they defined a new function `:=` which allows you to use names for parameters

```
rlang::list2("lab1" = "my_lab1", 
               !!paste0("lab", "2") := "my_lab2")
# $lab1
# [1] "my_lab1"
# $lab2
# [1] "my_lab2"
```

but in order to do this, it's just not possible to use `=`, they had to use `:=` which is a function in R, not a special character, and they manually re-write the call when executing it.

Comment: A nice added reference might be [Expressions / Function Calls](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Function-calls-_0028expressions_0029) from the R Language Definition. It specifies that a function argument can be "tagged" as `tag = expr` and that the tag can be "an identifier or a text string", but (implied by omission), not an expression.